# How to make icons align in vertical center with the navigation links?

Tags: html, css

I want to align the social media icon on the right in the center of the navigation bar along with the navigation link and logo. the navigation links are made using ul,li elements. and the social icons are in the div. I'm not getting should I use grid or flexbox or inline-block to get the desired UI.This is what I'm trying to do
[desired UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKzub.png)

```css
.Navigation {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
  
}

.Navigation li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin: 0 40px;
}

.social img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.social a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 16px;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
}

.social_center {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Collab</a></li>
        <li>
          <img
            class="logo"
            src="https://cdn.glitch.global/28f44676-40fa-4a71-b1c4-0fcb52be7382/Logo.png?v=1649644172153"
            width="175px"
            height="105px"
          />
        </li>

        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      
     
         <div class="social_center">
 
      <div class="social">
       <div class="youtube icon ">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3DkFux8Iv-aYnTRWzwaiBA">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.glitch.global/ea44df9f-5322-47c9-83ba-4f453113a115/Frame.png?v=1650775255106"
          />
        </a>
     </div>

      <div class="instagram icon ">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/petermckinnon/">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.glitch.global/ea44df9f-5322-47c9-83ba-4f453113a115/Frame-1.png?v=1650775235821"
          />
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="facebook icon">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/petermckinnonphoto">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.glitch.global/ea44df9f-5322-47c9-83ba-4f453113a115/Frame-2.png?v=1650775245589"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="twitter icon">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/petermckinnon">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.glitch.global/ea44df9f-5322-47c9-83ba-4f453113a115/Frame-3.png?v=1650775250222"
          />
        </a>
      </div>
        </div>
             </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.Navigation {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

If it isn't what you want - please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use display flex to your navigation main container, ul and also to the social icons container.

The idea is to make the main container flex its child to a row, the same with social icons container. You can check sample below:

```css
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
}

.navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 16px;
}

.navigation li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.social {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.social img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.social a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 16px;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Collab</a></li>
      <li>
        <img
          class="logo"
          src="https://cdn.glitch.global/28f44676-40fa-4a71-b1c4-0fcb52be7382/Logo.png?v=1649644172153"
          width="175px"
          height="105px"
        />
      </li>

      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>


  <div class="social_center">

    <div class="social">
     <div class="youtube icon ">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3DkFux8Iv-aYnTRWzwaiBA">
        <img
          src="https://cdn.glitch.global/ea44df9f-5322-47c9-83ba-4f453113a115/Frame.png?v=1650775255106"
        />
      </a>
   </div>

    <div class="instagram icon ">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/petermckinnon/">
        <img
          src="https://cdn.glitch.global/ea44df9f-5322-47c9-83ba-4f453113a115/Frame-1.png?v=1650775235821"
        />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="facebook icon">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/petermckinnonphoto">
        <img
          src="https://cdn.glitch.global/ea44df9f-5322-47c9-83ba-4f453113a115/Frame-2.png?v=1650775245589"
        />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="twitter icon">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/petermckinnon">
        <img
          src="https://cdn.glitch.global/ea44df9f-5322-47c9-83ba-4f453113a115/Frame-3.png?v=1650775250222"
        />
      </a>
    </div>
      </div>
           </div>
  </div>
```